# Verifying amount of elements using expect

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

So I have an element identified

```
var errorAlert = element.all('[id*="type-alert"]');
```

I am trying to create a function that will verify there are 2 alerts displayed..

```
this.isAlertsDisplayed = function() {
    return expect(errorAlert.count()).toEqual(2);
};
```

I keep gettin a friken typeError : .toEqual is not a function when I have seen this example work for others.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Danny is on the right track. Except that you are simply missing the `by.css()` part, replace:

```
var errorAlert = element.all('[id*="type-alert"]');
```

with:

```
var errorAlert = element.all(by.css('[id*="type-alert"]'));
```

Or with:

```
var errorAlert = $$('[id*="type-alert"]');
```

---

Note that you can spot this kind of problems much earlier in the process - statically even before executing your tests and trying to figure out what went wrong. If you would use [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org/) and [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) (>=1.29.0), the [`valid-locator-type` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-locator-type.md) would warn you if you have passed a literal to `element()` or `element.all()`, or if you have passed a "by" locator to `$()` or `$$()`.

And, if you have `ESLint` configured in your IDE of choice, here is how you would get the warning during the live-coding (example from PyCharm):

[image]

Comment: tried with $$ as well but same result. I ended up just altering the method to look for the last one, that way if there was 0 it would still fail.

Comment: @Tree55Topz your problem inspired me to get back to the `valid-locator-type` ESLint rule I was planning to finish. Now it's ready and published. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

your locator is wrong. Your locator should have **by.css() or by.id or something like this**.

Try `var errorAlert = $$('[id="type-alert"]') or
var errorAlert = element.all(by.id('type-alert'))`